# How is Chrome detecting an input field as credential Autofill?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have some input fields in my html DOM which have absolutely nothing special, but Chrome offers me the saved credentials when I click on it.
This is annoying if you have a field which only contains a persons name for example.
As this is not on all of my input fields, there must be a reason why Chrome means that this is a credential field?
Does anyone know what is triggering Chrome to offer his credential auto-complete window on an input field?

This is an example:

```
<label><input type="text" class="feFilterNameId filterInput" value=""></label>

.filterInput /* input box for edit window */.  
{
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    width: 97%;
    height: 16px;
    color: var(--filter-text-color);  
}
```

Comment: You can add  `autocomplete="off"` to disable it

Comment: No, Chrome is ignoring that

Answer (score 2):

This article may have helpful information regarding your issue. Hope it helps.

[Disabling-Chrome-Autofill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill)

Key bits of information that seem to be the most relevant to your issue:

Use **autocomplete="false"** instead of **autocomplete="off"** as the latter does not work on Chrome. (Some say it works, others say it does not. You'll just have to test it yourself)

Here's a quote from the article -

> It's silly that we have to resort to this, but the only sure way is to
> try and confuse the browser as much as possible:
>
> Name your inputs without leaking any information to the browser, i.e.
> id="field1" instead of id="country".
>
> Set autocomplete="do-not-autofill", basically use any value that won't
> let the browser recognize it as an autofillable field.

As well as this -

> Chrome now ignores . Therefore my original
> workaround (which I had deleted) is now all the rage.
>
> Simply create a couple of fields and make them hidden with
> "display:none". Example:

```
<!-- fake fields are a workaround for chrome autofill getting the wrong fields -->
<input style="display: none" type="text" name="fakeusernameremembered" />
<input style="display: none" type="password" name="fakepasswordremembered" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this link

[Disabling Chrome Autofill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15738259/disabling-chrome-autofill)

and trying many things I could find a solution for my problem.

As I do not use forms, I just put a

```
<form action = "javascript:void(0)"></form>
```

around the input fields which trigger the autocomplete on mistake.